# How to show only oldest and newest node in Drupal views?

Tags: views, blocks

I want to create a view that only shows the oldest and newest node of a certain content type what is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a contextual filter in view, and take a look at the below image to select any of these creation dates?

[image: screenshot]

Afterwards, filter your content type as in the following image:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Reader beware: this is probably a bad idea. But I couldn't resist.

```
function example_views_query_my_view_name_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $query->addExpression("ABS(nid - (SELECT MAX(nid) + MIN(nid) FROM {node} WHERE type='mynodetype') / 2)", 'horrificorder');
  $query->orderBy('horrificorder', 'DESC');
}
```

(Of course add a node type filter and display only two items in the Views UI.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can build two displays, one to show the oldest and other to show newest, and one to show (in each display) only one item per page without pager (in "Pager settings" of your view). Then, you can pull/show/embed these two displays where you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually only want to show the oldest and the newest, none of the ones in between?

Comment: I guess that you can build two displays, one to show the oldest and other to show newest, and show (in each display) only one item per page without pager (In Pager settings of your View). Then you can pull/show/embed these two displays where you need. I hope have understood well

Comment: Thankyou, but I needed these on the same view so I can make a calculation between two values that are in the nodes, or can I do this with 2 different views?

Answer (score 0):

"...I needed these on the same view so I can make a calculation..."

Getting calculations generated from Views results will take php coding skill and a knowledge of how Drupal is generating and displaying a page.