# How can I make this with the Views module?

Tags: views

I am trying to find out how to make a view which, in pseudo code, does this:

> If year = 2005 and month = 04 and page = 2 then display 2 articles

I have Views3 installed, but I can't find out how to make the date filter, and how to make the page filter.

Answer (score 1):

[How to show only oldest and newest node in Drupal views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14264/how-to-show-only-oldest-and-newest-node-in-drupal-views/14279#14279)

Check this out, I believe you will definately get answer with views, contextual filters.
and with the content type = Article and display only 2 with help of PAGER..

Extended answer

[image]

And when select that option, you will get another pop like below image

[image]

After making up a selection, write how many items you want to display.

[image]

And if you want to add see the month, why you just add fields to display.
also add a content posted date field below image will help out

[image]

Comment: Oke, 
So I have to take care that the month and year are in the url ?

Comment: And how can I check for the pagenumber. In the contextual filters is nothing to find about it.

Comment: Hello, I did not work. I made this filter (http://imagebin.org/181233) nothing changes on the page. See this (http://test.tamarawobben.nl/?q=blog&page=1)

Comment: Oke, I did find this but my real question is how I can check which month I am and on which page I am.

Comment: so do you want to display month and would you brief me about the "on which page I am", is it the content type like article or blog or custom type like

Comment: Hello, The whole site is a blog so it's a blog custom type.Thanks for the answer but what I mean is that I want to make a selection with the month not displaying the month. What I want is to make a selection which is based on the posted month and the page the articles are on. Based on that selection I want to change the number of articles displayed

Comment: So I made a blog which not contains 3 articles. What I want is on this page (http://test.tamarawobben.nl) display 1 article and on this page (http://test.tamarawobben.nl/?q=blog&page=1) display 2 articles. So the page is the number which Drupal place behind the &page=

Comment: I found out that I can check the posted month and year with the contextual filter posted date. But I cannot find how I can check the value of the &page= .

Answer (score 1):

As @JoeS instructed, you likely can accomplish what you want simply by limiting the number of posts per page to 2 and ordering by chronology.

If however, you did want to show the only posts for April, 2005 with two posts per page, you could pass the values through the URL and use two contextual filters to display the posts that match.

First add the Contextual filters for "Content: Created month" and "Content: Created year"

Then configure the filters to use the default values from the URL, or by matching values from the current Date

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you are doing with the page=2 then show 2 articles. Are you referring to the second page of the view? Are the 2 articles the first two results of the view?  Could you please clarify the question a bit?

When you define a view to select certain articles you set the limit for how many appear on the display first page.  The page gives the user the means to access any additional results. The order of the results is set by the sort settings.  IF you want specific articles to appear on a specific page of the view display you must address the order they are sorted. (You could add a number field to the articles to set the order you want and then sort by the field value).

Looking at your view settings, I believe your path is incorrect.  The path setting is the name of the URL for the view. Give it a name such as /blog/blogtype/(# or name). Your filter settings will select only blogs as set.  If you want to filter further then change the path to blog/blogtype/% and use a contextual filter to get what you want. (There is much to learn to use views effectively.  I recommend you check out the video series "taming the Beast' at nodeone.se to get a handle on how it works.

Comment: Oke, I try to clearify. I have the page http://test.tamarawobben.nl with 1 article and a link to page 2. On page2 there is also 1 article. I mean then this (http://test.tamarawobben.nl/?q=blog&page=1) page. There I like to have 2 articles instead of 1 article.

Comment: Your question and clarification lead me to think you may be overlooking the real power of views. Views is capable of searching all of your nodes, selecting the ones you define, sorting them, and displaying them automatically.  You tell it how many articles to display on the view form. To create a static page with two articles, the easiest way is to create a page and write the two articles directly on on it.  I recommend you Watch the video series I mentioned above, it will open up a lot of options for you in your site planning.

Comment: Oke, I will watch the video's and hope I will find the answer there. I think the answer is somewhere in the contextual filters.